# How to get list post data in django forms?

Tags: django, forms

my form serialize like this:

`server_ids=6&server_ids=9`

and in views using getlist can get list data successful:

`request.POST.getlist('server_ids')`

but How can I **define** 'server_ids' in django.forms class?

For example, in my forms class:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    server_ids = forms.MultiValueField()
```

I tried models.MultipleChoiceField, TypedMultipleChoiceField, MultiValueField...But the form valid get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean that:

`self.data.getlist('server_ids')`

You can call it in a form class. e.g. in a `clean` method

Here is an example for your other question:

```
SERVER_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
)
server_ids = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=SERVER_CHOICES)
```

It is also helpful if you take a look at the documentations about [Django widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/)

Comment: My mean is how to get 'server_ids' in a forms class, not in views. Thanks your answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in your form class i.e. in the `clean()` method. Try it.

Comment: Oh...I update my question. I want to define the field in forms class. But forms.MultiValueField() not work. Any other way?

Comment: Do you want a multiple integer input field?

Comment: Yes. In html, it's a multiple choose.

Comment: I update my answer with an example. Did you already tried that one?

Comment: Almost success. But my choice in html not stable. How?

Comment: What do you mean with "stable" ? Could you specify your problems more clearly? Please do not forget to mark my answer as solved.

Comment: I understand your mean just now. using `return self.data.getlist('server_ids')` in clean_<fieldname>() method can get list data. Thanks again!